# dlopen fails in eclipse but works on ddd

Tags: eclipse, shared-libraries

I am working on a project where when I copy the .ddd directory from an older project member, I am able to debug a binary which links to a .so file.

But when I try to setup eclipse dlopen fails. In "Debug Configurations -> Debugger -> Shared Libraries" I have included the directory where the .so file exists. I have also added the same path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I would really appreciated any pointers to solution to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution !! Under Debug Configurations -> Arguments Tab, uncheck the "Use Default" checkbox and put the path to the binary under "Working Directory".